Tagpdf, hyperref, and redefinition of l@section
When I use tagging and rededine \l@section, links from TOC are no longer produced.  MWE
\DocumentMetadata{
  pdfversion=2.0,pdfstandard=ua-2,
  testphase={phase-III,math,firstaid,title},
  lang={en-US}
}


\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
  \parindent \z@
  \leavevmode
  #1\nobreak\hfill#2\par
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{First}
Section body
\clearpage
\section{Second}
Section body
\end{document}

If I delete \DocumentMetadata, the links are there.

the tagged/linking versions are in latex2e/required/latex-lab/latex-lab-toc-kernel-changes.dtx and your redefinition removes all the tagging code so things are out of sync as the rest of the heading.table of contents code is assuming the latex-lab deinitions

This is what I was looking for.  Many thanks, David!

@DavidCarlisle answered this question in the comments.  I just put his answer here for the community
This works:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
  \parindent \z@
  \leavevmode
  \UseHookWithArguments{contentsline/text/before}{4}
  {\toclevel@section}{#1}{#2}{\@contentsline@destination}%
  #1%
  \UseHookWithArguments{contentsline/text/after}{4}
  {\toclevel@section}{#1}{#2}{\@contentsline@destination}%
  \nobreak\hfill
  \UseHookWithArguments{contentsline/page/before}{4}
  {\toclevel@section}{#1}{#2}{\@contentsline@destination}%
  #2%
  \UseHookWithArguments{contentsline/page/after}{4}
  {\toclevel@section}{#1}{#2}{\@contentsline@destination}%
  \par
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


This is not the final code, the tagging code will probably at some time move out of the hooks into tagging sockets (so that it position is clear)

You are right, but at this point I am typesetting a book, not writing a class.  I want the code to work once
